# IPC with imsg? OpenBSD and Linux compatibility?

Tags: linux, ipc, openbsd

I was reading the [Tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) source to see how it works. It saw that it uses `imsg` for its IPC, which I had never even heard of. I've been trying to find out more, but it turns out `imsg` is kind of hard to google, and I get a lot of results for iMessage.

[I found some `imsg` documentation here,](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=imsg_read&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&sektion=3&format=html) so it seems to be an OpenBSD library. I started looking for a Linux implementation, but I can't find anything. It appears the author(s) of Tmux wrote their own compatibility layer. This kind of surprises me, because `imsg` seems like it would be really useful. Does Linux have a similar C API for this, that I just don't know about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick look at the build script shows the following three files:

- [compat/imsg-buffer.c](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/tree/master/compat/imsg-buffer.c)
- [compat/imsg.c](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/tree/master/compat/imsg.c)
- [compat/imsg.h](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/tree/master/compat/imsg.h)

So the tmux authors ship a copy of OpenBSD's `imsg` library, which is implemented entirely in user-space.

Comment: Pretty nice.  Someone should package this up as a library.